# How to quit the event loop of a worker QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm writing an application with a button to start/stop a worker thread (which implements `QThread`).
The worker thread keeps scheduling a job every few milliseconds.
To terminate the worker thread, I'm calling `worker.quit()` (`worker.exit(0)` doesn't work either) method from the GUI thread and waiting the `finished` signal to be fired.

The problem is that even though the `finished` signal is fired, the thread isn't terminated.

Here is a minimal example:
https://gist.github.com/NawfelBgh/941babdc011f07aa4ab61570d7b88f08

[image: screenshot of the minimal example]

#### Edit

My interpretation of what happened was wrong: **The worker thread was being terminated** but the method `iter` was getting executed in the main thread as said by @sergey-tachenov and as confirmed from the logging generated with the code:

```
void run() {
    std::cout <<"From worker thread: "<<QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
...
void iter() {
    std::cout <<"From thread: "<<QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    std::cout <<"From main thread: "<<QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
```

I switched to a [different design](https://gist.github.com/NawfelBgh/4e7b98b0151e483129517674d29a7c5f) which doesn't rely on `QTimer`s. But I didn't submit it as an answer since the title of this question is "How to quit the event loop of a worker QThread".

Comment: Try `void QThread::terminate() `  The thread may or may not be terminated immediately, depending on the operating system's scheduling policies. Listen for the  `terminated()  ` signal, or use  `QThread::wait() ` after  ` terminate() `, to be sure.
When the thread is terminated, all threads waiting for the thread to finish will be woken up. Also, check [What is the correct way to stop QThread?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/20539/what-is-the-correct-way-to-stop-qthread/2) if you haven't see it already.

Comment: @M010, `terminate` is a very dangerous thing that should not be used at all except in maybe debugging or testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread is terminated. Only your timer runs not in the thread you've started but in the main thread, that's why it isn't stopped. This is because it uses queued connections by default and the thread object lives in the thread in which it was created which is the main thread. To fix it:

- Do *not* subclass `QThread`. It's usually a bad idea unless you want to actually extend `QThread`'s functionality.
- Create a separate worker object that inherits `QObject`.
- Use `moveToThread` to move the worker object to the created thread. It will cause all its slots to fire actually in the thread. If you use default or queued connections, that is.

[The `QThread` docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) provide an excellent example on that (the first one).

Note that if you actually want to use data provided by the thread to update GUI, you'll have to somehow correctly publish that data to the GUI thread (possibly using `emit` and queued connections) instead of trying to update GUI directly from the thread. And if you want to access shared data, you probably need to guard it with a `QMutex`, not like you do with your shared counter.